# how to load value in textbox from datepicker in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview with 2 textbox.text1 loads data on viewdidload function.
for text2, the input is dates. I am using tableview didselectrow method to show datepicker. but when i select date from datepicker, it is printing in console but not added in textbox.

`  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

```
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    datePickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 200, 290, 200.0)
    datePickerContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    datePickerContainer.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    datePickerContainer.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    var pickerSize : CGSize = datePicker.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20, pickerSize.width, 160)

    //datePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: true)
    //datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "dateChangedInDate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    datePickerContainer.addSubview(datePicker)

    var doneButton = UIButton()
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dismissPicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    doneButton.frame    = CGRectMake(130.0, 160, 70.0, 37.0)

    datePickerContainer.addSubview(doneButton)

    self.view.addSubview(datePickerContainer)

}

func dateChangedInDate(sender:UIDatePicker){

    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let selectedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    firstIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedIndex, inSection: 0)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(firstIndex) as! mytableviewcell
    cell.dateText.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

   // print(selectedDate)


}
```

`
Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try making all updates to cells inside the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method. Make it so that the `text` of your label is bound to the `DatePicker` value. Then, inside your `dataChangedWithDate()` method, trigger a table update of the row in question using `table.reloadRowsAtIndexPath()`. Note that I'm assuming `selectedIndex` is an instance variable for your controller, so that you have access to it inside the `dateChangedWithDate()` method.

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue the cell, perform all of your other tasks for laying out the cell
    // {...}

    // Bind the label's text to the DatePicker value
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    cell.dateText.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
}

func dateChangedInDate(sender:UIDatePicker){
    // Trigger table update for the selected row
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedIndex, inSection:0)
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
create Variable to store data value.
// var dateTime = ""
//cellForIndexMethod
 cell.dateText.text = dateTime


func dateChangedInDate(sender:UIDatePicker){

 dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
 dateTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
 let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: selectedIndex, inSection:0)

 //Reload table
   self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

}
```